# Change the texture/image of one side of a CircleGeometry object within a time interval

Tags: javascript, three.js

So **I'm absolutely new** to Three.js. I just took a brief crash course, so now I understand the 1% of its power.

For my website, I made possible to have a rotating disc with an image/texture of mine, but I wish that **one side's texture/image of that disc/circle change for another one by a time interval**  I mean, when 5 sec. pass, change it, then another 5 sec. change it again to the previous one, and so back and forth.

As I said, I'm absolutely new to this, so I don't know how. I know basic/semiadvanced js stuff, though.

My code:

```
// Cubito 3D hecho en three.js

// Selecciona el div con el # especificado.
let cubo3d = document.querySelector('#cubo3d')
// Estos valores dependen de los del CSS para que cuadre bien el cubo en su posición.
let CANVAS_WIDTH = 450;
let CANVAS_HEIGHT = 450;

let scene = new THREE.Scene();
let camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, (CANVAS_WIDTH / CANVAS_HEIGHT), 0.1, 1000);
let renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
let geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(6, 32);

// Imágenes a cargar en cada lado del cubo.
let cubeMaterials = [
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load('{{ "/assets/gifs/yo.jpg" }}'),
        side: THREE.DoubleSide
    })
];
let material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(cubeMaterials);
let circle = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);

// Velocidades de rotación
let rotX = 0.008;
let rotY = 0.009;

//Cubo
scene.add(circle);

camera.position.z = 10;

renderer.setSize(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
cubo3d.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

animate();

function animate() {
    circle.rotation.x += rotX;
    circle.rotation.y += rotY;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

// Resize responsivo
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    let width = CANVAS_WIDTH;
    let height = CANVAS_HEIGHT;
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    camera.aspect = width/height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your variable naming convention is pretty confusing because you use `cubeXX` and `circleXX` interchangeably, so I'm just going to provide some pseudocode. The idea is that you can load 2 textures, then use [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to swap them every 5 seconds:

```
// Load 2 separate textures
let textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
let texture1 = textureLoader.load("/assets/gifs/yo.jpg");
let texture2 = textureLoader.load("/assets/gifs/yoTambien.jpg");

// Build geom, material & mesh
let circleGeom = new THREE.CircleGeometry(6, 32);
let circleMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    map: texture1,
    side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
let circleMesh = new THREE.Mesh(circleGeom, circleMat);
scene.add(circleMesh);

// Sets an interval to be called every 5000 miliseconds
window.setInterval(swapTextures, 5000);

// Checks the active texture, and swaps it for the other
function swapTextures() {
    if (circleMat.map === texture1) {
        circleMat.map = texture2;
    } else {
        circleMat.map = texture1;
    }
}
```

Sidenote: Which crash course did you take, if you don't mind me asking? `MeshFaceMaterial` [has been deprecated since 2015](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/6353)

Comment: Thanks. And sorry for the naming convention, usually I experiment and forget to format correctly. Also, one I downloaded form a russian site.

Comment: Also, would like to ask you, why if is that deprecated, it still works? And what would be the consequences of using it?

Comment: I'm using revision 97 of Three.js, and I get a console warning "THREE.MeshFaceMaterial has been removed. Use an Array instead." and it simply returns the array that was used to construct it. In future revisions, this helpful warning+conversion might be removed altogether and your code will break.